# pedestrian detection from desktop screen

Tags: python, opencv, detection, screen-capture

i want to know how to use desktop video source instead of webcam video source in the first code. the bottom code is the desktop video i want to use in the top code.

This first code is from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pedestrian-detection-using-opencv-python/

```
import cv2
import imutils
   
# Initializing the HOG person
# detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
   
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4')
   
while cap.isOpened():
    # Reading the video stream
    ret, image = cap.read()
    if ret:
        image = imutils.resize(image, 
                               width=min(400, image.shape[1]))
   
        # Detecting all the regions 
        # in the Image that has a 
        # pedestrians inside it
        (regions, _) = hog.detectMultiScale(image,
                                            winStride=(4, 4),
                                            padding=(4, 4),
                                            scale=1.05)
   
        # Drawing the regions in the 
        # Image
        for (x, y, w, h) in regions:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y),
                          (x + w, y + h), 
                          (0, 0, 255), 2)
   
        # Showing the output Image
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
  
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the above code works for pedestrian detection from video.mp4 source.

I do not know how to get the code above to work with the code "sct_img" below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss

bounding_box = {'top': 0, 'left': 550, 'width': 1080, 'height': 720}

sct = mss()

while True:
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)

    image_data = np.asarray(sct_img)

    cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(image_data))

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

i tried to monkey my way to make it work but i failed so i come here for help.

Answer (score 0):

I installed obs studio version 29.1.3

I opened obs,

below "sources" is a '+' sign, I clicked that and clicked display capture,

I clicked "start virtual camera",

and then in the pedestrian code instead of the mp4 file, I used

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_ANY, params=[
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920,
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080])
```

to get the native resolution i use code in the parenthesis after the number 1. but the pedestrian code doen't work very well with the native resolution.

and got the picture of my desktop detecting pedestrians on youtube test video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doCahM4-zUA

the below code works a bit better for pedestrian detection while in native 1080p resolution

```
import cv2
import imutils

# Initializing the HOG person
# detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(
    1,
    apiPreference=cv2.CAP_ANY,
    params=[cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920, cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080],
)

while cap.isOpened():
    # Reading the video stream
    ret, image = cap.read()
    if ret:

        # Detecting all the regions
        # in the Image that has a
        # pedestrians inside it
        (regions, _) = hog.detectMultiScale(
            image, winStride=(8, 8), padding=(16, 16), scale=1.04
        )

        # Drawing the regions in the
        # Image
        for (x, y, w, h) in regions:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Showing the output Image
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```